# Shadow on floating action button

Tags: android, android-studio

For some reason a small shadow appears on top of my floating action button as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AqoD.png) but only on the debugging device but not in the Android Studio preview.

The button is nested in a relative layout to position it in the bottom of the screen like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_play_circle_outline_white_36" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Update:**

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PKDowmJ2S_u8ZXS3h5GhzVKapJ_w-gB9/edit) is what it looks like when clicked.
The problem is also caused by adding an alpha value to the FAB like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117518/alpha-applied-to-floating-action-button-creates-weird-circle)
but in my case, as the shadow color is almost the same as the original, adding 0.9 alpha makes it way less obvious.

Comment: For positioning the FAB you should prefer the CoordinatorLayout over the RelativeLayout. It will move the FAB, when you show a Snackbar or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

try adding following attributes to fab :

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, i have updated my question